# Format code in Bluefish?

Tags: format, code, bluefish

I asked a similar question on `webmasters.stackexchange.com` and was directed here.

How do I format code in Bluefish HTML editor? There's auto-indenting, that's easy enough to find. Is there a button I can click after selecting all the text? Because I sure can't seem to find it.

Comment: Which version of Bluefish?

Comment: I'm using Bluefish 2.0.3 on Fedora 16. I installed through `yum`

Answer (score 3):

For html files I could find this functionality under `Tools` -> `Filters` -> `Tidy HTML`. Notice that you need [HTML Tidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidy/) installed<sup>1</sup>. I personally prefer to also have the file auto-indented: `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `External filters` -> `Tidy XML: |tidy -i|`.

Additionally, for xml files you can add a new "Tidy XML" label with corresponding command `|tidy -xml -i|`.

---

<sup>1</sup> In Gentoo: `sudo emerge -v app-text/htmltidy`; in Debian, `sudo apt-get install tidy`; in Fedora, I would guess `sudo yum install tidy`?

Comment: The above Bluefish command is similar to typing the command `tidy -im file.html` in a bash shell, outside of Bluefish. Just mentioning this as the builtin filter gave an error for me.

Comment: my new, default installation of bluefish (on ubuntu 17.04) used `perltidy` as the html tidy tool, requiring it to be installed first, rather than html tidy, which I did already have installed. It does seem to depend on which menu option one is actually invoking; some use `tidy`, some `perltidy`(viewing the preferences "external filters" shows which tools need to be used)